# Record traffic from production server and them send to development

Tags: windows, iis, server

We are trying to reproduce the load of production IIS server in our development IIS server (to evaluate the impact of changes in database indexes)
I dont know is its possible to record the IIS traffic on production server to them    send this traffic to development server.
Neither knows if this is the correct approach to acomplish this task
Can yo help me? Thanks

PD: We are using Windows Server 2008 SE

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need reverse proxy with URL rewrite. When you build reverse proxy in production server, Production server will record requests and will traffic all requests to your development server.

So please install Application request routing and URL rewrite then create reverse proxy rule to traffic requests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Thanks for your answer
If I understood you, reverse proxy sends production server request to development server in "real time".
Will this take effect un production perfomance?

Comment: It shouldn't have much impact on production performance. Because development server mainly handle the request and development server only works as a proxy. Besides, URL rewrite support regex expression, so you can decide which part require to be rewritten and which part not.